# Branes at the conifold

Tags: string-theory, gauge-theory, branes

Consider $N$ $D3$-branes at the singularity of the conifold. This particular example can be viewed as a $AdS_{5} \times T^{1,1}$ in the near horizon limit, where the Einstein manifold has isometry $SU(2)\times SU(2) \times U(1)$. The geometry will be dual to a superconformal $SU(N) \times SU(N)$ $\mathcal{N}=1$ gauge theory, [hep-th/9807080](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9807080). How to derive the gauge theory from the Klebanov-Witten background?

Comment: Please give a bit more details. *Which* conifold? How are the $D_3$-branes arranged? Do you know how one gets a low-energy theory in general? What is troubling about this specific case?

Comment: Comment to the question (v1): Echoing comment by @ACuriousMind: Consider adding references to make the question more accessible to the reader and focus the answers.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. Well, the conifold is a cone over an Einstein manifold, T^{(1,1)}. I don't know how to get the low-energy theory, it could be a better idea taking an easy background, for instance. Could you please provide me some ideas how to extract the low-energy theory? I would like to understand how to construct the gauge theory for the Klebanov-Witten background and also for the Klebanov-Tseytlin background